# strtok changing value of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

i have the following code:

```
char* pathTokens;
char* paths;
paths = getFilePaths();

//printf("%s", paths);

pathTokens = strtok(paths, "\n");

updateFile(pathTokens, argv[1]);
```

and these variables in the same file as updateFile():

```
static FILE* file;
static char content[1024];
static char* token;
static int numChanges = 0;

static char newContent[1024];
```

Here is updateFile():

```
void updateFile(char pathTokens[], char searchWord[]) {
    while(pathTokens != NULL) {
        printf("Token: %s\n", pathTokens);
        updateNewContent(pathTokens, searchWord);

        pathTokens = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}
```

and updateNewContent():

```
static void updateNewContent(char fileName[], char searchWord[]) {
    if(searchWord == NULL) {
        printf("Please enter a word\n");
        return;
    }
    numChanges = 0;
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return;
    }


    while(fgets(content, 1024, file) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(content, " ");
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

whenever `token = strtok(content, " ");` is called, the value of `pathTokens` changes. if i comment it out, `pathTokens` maintains its original values. i don't want `pathTokens` to change, so why is `strtok` modifying it?

Comment: As per man page of `strtok` "Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token. This string does not include the delimiting byte. If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL."  you passing pointer address, it's change what it points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nesting `strtok` calls and `strtok` doesn't work like that. For nesting
calls you have to use `strtok_r`.

Also, when calling `strtok`, only the first time the source argument must be
used, for all subsequent calls, `NULL` has to be used. When you call `strtok`
again with an non-`NULL` argument, `strtok` "forgets" about the last state and
"restarts" parsing new content.

When you do in `updateNewContent` you are doing:

```
while(fgets(content, 1024, file) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(content, " ");
}
```

`strtok` will forget about `paths` (the very first call). Also this loop is
pointless, you read a line, you split it for the first time, and then read the
next line, split it again, etc. You are doing nothing with `token`. When the
loop ends `token` will store the first word of the last line.

And then the function returns and you do

```
pathTokens = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

Because you call it with `NULL`, it will look continue parsing the contents
pointed to by `content`, which seems to be a global variable.

> whenever `token = strtok(content, " ");` is called, the value of `pathTokens` changes

Of course it does, after `updateNewContent` returns, you assign a new value to
it. What else did you expect?

I really don't know what you are trying to do here, to me that makes no sense.
If you need to do a `strtok` with a token that previously returned by another
`strtok`, then you have to use `strtok_r`.

Here is an example of how to nest `strtok`:

```
char line[] = "a:b:c,d:e:f,x:y:z";

char *s1, *s2, *token1, *token2, *in1, *in2;

in1 = line;

while(token1 = strtok_r(in1, ",", &s1))
{
    in1 = NULL; // for subsequent calls

    in2 = token1;

    printf("First block: %s\n", token1);

    while(token2 = strtok_r(in2, ":", &s2))
    {
        in2 = NULL; // for subsequent calls

        printf("  val: %s\n", token2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First block: a:b:c
  val: a
  val: b
  val: c
First block: d:e:f
  val: d
  val: e
  val: f
First block: x:y:z
  val: x
  val: y
  val: z
```

Comment: I removed some commented code, that's why it's unclear as to what it does (a mistake on my part), but you were right about using strtok_r. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you use strtok() function it means that you want to divide your input into tokens. Like that when you given input strtok(pathtokens,"") ,divides into tokens and prints even though there is pointer variable